# How to get program variable set correctly

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write code that will return equal dividers of a given number. I don't know where I'm wrong. Any help?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std; // So the program can see cout and endl


int main()
{
    int Numerator;
    cout<<"Enter Numerator: ";
    cin>>Numerator;

    int Denominator = 1;
    while (Denominator < Numerator) {
        int divresult;
        int check;
        divresult = (Numerator / Denominator);
        check = divresult * Denominator;
        if(check = Numerator){
                cout << divresult <<endl;
        }
        Denominator++;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Desired Output:

```
9
3
1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: you probably mean `if(check == Numerator)` but it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if(check = Numerator){
```

is wrong.  Checking for equality is done with `==`, while `=` causes the value of `Numerator` to be assigned to `check`, and then the `if` expression is true if the new value is true.  Your compiler should have given you a warning about this mistake; if it didn't, turn on warnings.  If it did, pay more attention to the warnings.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
if(check = Numerator){
```

should be

```
if(check == Numerator){
```

You need `==` to check equality. `=` is for assignment. Your compiler should have given you a warning.

Also, if you want the output `1` you also need to change the line:

```
while (Denominator < Numerator) {
```

to

```
while (Denominator <= Numerator) {
```

Comment: thanks! I figured that out after playing around with it.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the comparison operator is `==`

```
if ( check == Numerator ) { ...
```